# Conserns in Rails 5 are not loading

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I can't for the live of me get a consern to load in an app I'm building.  I'm using this for server-side processing with datatables.

Just in case it's messing with something I'm including the structure of the module, where I have one general module with a bunch of stuff that is defined by specialized modules that have classes  which include the general module.  The intent being to use definitions inside the specialized classes for the different types of data found in different tables without having to repeat a bunch of code.

- I've checked the capitalization of the files as mentioned in another
  post.
- I've tried it both with and without the "extend
  ActiveSupport::Concern" inside the module.
- I've tried changing the module name in case
  it was clashing with something else.
- I've tried adding "::" in front
  of the include from another post.

I haven't even gotten to the

The error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant MetatasksController::MetatasksDatatableModule):

app/controllers/metatasks_controller.rb:2:in `<class:MetatasksController>'
app/controllers/metatasks_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

My controller (/app/controllers/metatasks_controller.rb) has this:

```
class MetatasksController < ApplicationController
  include MetatasksDatatableModule
  [...]
end
```

The consern (/app/controllers/concerns/metatask_datatables_consern.rb) has this:

```
module MetatasksDatatableModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  class MetatasksDatatable
    include DatatableModule
    [...]
  end
end
```

The generalized datatable module (/app/controllers/concerns/datatables_module.rb) has this:

```
module DatatableModule
  included do
    [...]
  end
end
```

My autoload paths include the folder (edited for relevancy/privacy):

```
> rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'
[...]
/home/<user>/sites/<appname>/app/controllers/concerns
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite likely that Rails can't autoload because the filenames don't match the module names, and so it doesn't know where to load them from.

So `metatask_datatables_consern.rb` should be called `metatasks_datatable_module.rb` and `datatables_module.rb` should be `datatable_module.rb`

Comment: This Fixed it, thank you so much!  I was pullong my hair out for hours and litterally yell "what do you want from me?!" at my computer so it's pretty embarrasing is was something THAT simple.